# Java Fast Food Menu (using methods)

Tags: java, methods, menu

I'm writing a program that displays a fast food menu. The user selects an item, then enters the quantity of that item, and can continue selecting items with specific quantities until done. I have to use several methods. What I'm having trouble with is calculating a running total. This is my first Java class so I only know the basics. I put the running total in a while loop so it'll keep adding a subtotal to it, but when I call done() the runningTotal is 0. What's the best way to keep track of the running total while using multiple methods? Also, I'm open to any criticism or clean up in my code. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {
    public double subTotal;
    public static double runningTotal;
    private static double itemPrice;
    static boolean ordering = true;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void menu() {
        System.out.println("Welcome \n1. Burger ($2.00) \n2. Fries ($1.50)\n3. Soda ($1.00) \n4. Done");
    }

    public static double itemPrice(int foodItem) {
        if (foodItem == 1) {
            // burger= $2.00
            System.out.println("You've ordered a burger");
            itemPrice = 2.00;
        }
        if (foodItem == 2) {
            // fries = $1.50
            System.out.println("You've ordered fries");
            itemPrice = 1.50;
        }
        if (foodItem == 3) {
            // soda = $1.00
            System.out.println("You've ordered a soda");
            itemPrice = 1.00;
        }
        quantity();
        return itemPrice;
    }

    public static double quantity() {
        System.out.println("Enter quantity");
        double quantity = input.nextDouble();
        subTotal(quantity, itemPrice);
        return quantity;
    }

    public static double subTotal(double quantity, double itemPrice) {
        double subTotal = quantity * itemPrice;
        System.out.println("Subtotal: " + subTotal);
        return subTotal;
    }

    public static void done(double runningTotal) {
        ordering = false;
        System.out.println(runningTotal);
        System.out.println("Enjoy your meal");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int menuOption;
        int foodItem = 0;
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            double runningTotal = 0;
            menu();
            menuOption = input.nextInt();
            switch (menuOption) {
            case 1:
                foodItem = 1;
                itemPrice(foodItem);
                break;
            case 2:
                foodItem = 2;
                itemPrice(foodItem);
                break;
            case 3:
                foodItem = 3;
                itemPrice(foodItem);
                break;
            case 4:
                done(runningTotal);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid option.");
            }
        } while (ordering);
        {
            subTotal(quantity(), itemPrice(foodItem));
            runningTotal = runningTotal + subTotal(quantity(), itemPrice(foodItem));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the `double runningTotal=0;` in the while loop. Also the price returned by the `itemPrice` needs to be added into the `runningTotal` variable;

This is how your main method should look like. You are not required to call the `subTotal` method, once the user is done.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int menuOption;
  int foodItem = 0;
  input = new Scanner(System.in);
  double runningTotal=0;
  do{
    menu();
    menuOption = input.nextInt();
    switch(menuOption){
      case 1:
        foodItem = 1;
        runningTotal += itemPrice(foodItem);
        break;
      case 2:
        foodItem = 2;
        runningTotal += itemPrice(foodItem);
        break;
      case 3:
        foodItem = 3;
        runningTotal += itemPrice(foodItem);
        break;
      case 4:
        done(runningTotal);
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("Invalid option.");
    }
  } while(ordering);
  System.out.println("Total amount: " + runningTotal);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Welcome 
1. Burger ($2.00) 
2. Fries ($1.50)
3. Soda ($1.00) 
4. Done
1
You've ordered a burger
Enter quantity
2
Subtotal: 4.0
Welcome 
1. Burger ($2.00) 
2. Fries ($1.50)
3. Soda ($1.00) 
4. Done
2
You've ordered fries
Enter quantity
1
Subtotal: 1.5
Welcome 
1. Burger ($2.00) 
2. Fries ($1.50)
3. Soda ($1.00) 
4. Done
4
3.5
Enjoy your meal
Total amount: 3.5
```

Comment: `1.5` + `1` + `2` = `3.5`?

Answer (score 0):

You reset runningTotal to 0 every iteration. I have attached a working example. I moved the total calculation to your subTotal method where it adds every subTotal as they come in.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class menu {
public double subTotal;
public static double runningTotal;
private static double itemPrice;
static boolean ordering = true;
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void menu(){
    System.out.println("Welcome \n1. Burger ($2.00) \n2. Fries ($1.50)\n3. Soda ($1.00) \n4. Done");
}
public static double itemPrice(int foodItem) {
    if (foodItem == 1) {
        //burger= $2.00
        System.out.println("You've ordered a burger");
        itemPrice = 2.00;
    }
    if (foodItem == 2) {
        //fries = $1.50
        System.out.println("You've ordered fries");
        itemPrice = 1.50;
    }
    if (foodItem == 3) {
        //soda = $1.00
        System.out.println("You've ordered a soda");
        itemPrice = 1.00;
    }
    quantity();
    return itemPrice;
}
public static double quantity() {
    System.out.println("Enter quantity");       
    double quantity = input.nextDouble();
    subTotal(quantity, itemPrice);
    return quantity;
 }
public static double subTotal(double quantity, double itemPrice) {
    double subTotal = quantity*itemPrice;
    System.out.println("Subtotal: "+ subTotal);
    runningTotal += subTotal;
    return subTotal;
}
public static void done(){
    ordering = false;
    System.out.println(runningTotal);
    System.out.println("Enjoy your meal");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int menuOption;
    int foodItem = 0;
    input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    do{
        double runningTotal=0;
        menu();
        menuOption = input.nextInt();    
        switch(menuOption){
            case 1:
                foodItem = 1;
                itemPrice(foodItem);
                break;
            case 2:
                foodItem = 2;
                itemPrice(foodItem);
                break;
            case 3:
                foodItem = 3;
                itemPrice(foodItem);
                break;
            case 4:
                done();
                break;      
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid option.");
        }

    } while(ordering); {
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will bring the exact output.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Resteraunt 
    {
    public double subTotal;
    public static double runningTotal;
    private static double itemPrice;
    static boolean ordering = true;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static double j=0.0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int menuOption;
    int foodItem = 0;
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double runningTotal=0;
    while(ordering) 
    {
    menu();
    menuOption = input.nextInt();
    switch(menuOption){
    case 1:
    foodItem = 1;
    runningTotal += ItemPrice(foodItem);
    break;
    case 2:
    foodItem = 2;
    runningTotal += ItemPrice(foodItem);
    break;
    case 3:
    foodItem = 3;
    runningTotal += ItemPrice(foodItem);
    break;
    case 4:
    done(runningTotal);
    break;
    default:
    System.out.println("Invalid option.");
    }
    } 
    System.out.println("Total amount: $" + runningTotal);
    }
    public static void menu() {
    System.out.println("Welcome \n1. Burger ($2.00) \n2. Fries ($1.50)\n3. Soda 
    ($1.00) \n4. Done");
    }

    public static double ItemPrice(int foodItem) {
    if (foodItem == 1) {
        // burger= $2.00
        System.out.println("You've ordered a burger");
        itemPrice = 2.00;
    }
    if (foodItem == 2) {
        // fries = $1.50
        System.out.println("You've ordered fries");
        itemPrice = 1.50;
    }
    if (foodItem == 3) {
        // soda = $1.00
        System.out.println("You've ordered a soda");
        itemPrice = 1.00;
    }
    quantity();
    return j;
}

public static double quantity() {
    System.out.println("Enter quantity");
    double quantity = input.nextDouble();
    subTotal(quantity, itemPrice);
    return quantity;
}

public static double subTotal(double quantity, double itemPrice) {
    double subTotal = quantity * itemPrice;
    System.out.println("Subtotal: $" + subTotal);
    j=subTotal;
    return subTotal;
}

public static void done(double runningTotal) {
    ordering = false;
    System.out.println("Enjoy your meal");
}
}
```

Comment: Providing an explanation of issue and fix you made would be great for users